# loadDocumentNode with multiple models

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I can´t use the viewer.loadDocumentNode to aggregate models to my viewer. It always unload the current model and loads the one I want. Is it supposed to act like this?

When should I use loadModel or loadDocumentNode?

My sample code:

```
function documentLoaded(doc){
    viewables = avd.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {'type': 'geometry'}, true);
    if (viewables.length === 0) return;
    var initialViewable = viewables[0];
    var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
    var modelOptions = { sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
        ,globalOffset: {x:0, y:0, z:0}
        ,applyRefPoint: true 
    };
    viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess); // this one aggrerates a model
    //viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, initialViewable,modelOptions ); // this one changes the model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewer.loadModel`(doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback)) for model aggregation:

```
viewer.start(svfUrl,options,onSuccess); //Load first model
...
viewer.loadModel(svfUrl) //Second and later models
```

And use `viewer.loadDocumentNode`(doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options)) for loading specific bubble nodes of a model (to load parts of the model that is, not sure if `loadDocumentNode` supports aggregation at the moment - if you need this for multiple model consider aggregating the model prior to SVF translation):

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(lmvDoc, geometryItem, options)
```